# Finding the minimum positive value

Tags: r

I guess I don't know `which.min` as well as I thought.

I'm trying to find the occurrence in a vector of a minimum value that is positive.

```
TIME <- c(0.00000,  4.47104,  6.10598,  6.73993,  8.17467,  8.80862, 10.00980, 11.01080, 14.78110, 15.51520, 16.51620, 17.11680)
```

I want to know for the values `z` of 1 to 19, the index of the above vector TIME containing the value that is closest to but above `z`. I tried the following code:

```
vec <- sapply(seq(1,19,1), function(z) which.min((z-TIME > 0)))
vec 

#[1] 2  2  2  2  3  3  5  5  7  7  8  9  9  9 10 11 12  1  1
```

To my mind, the last two values of vec should be '12, 12'.   The reason it's doing this is because it thinks that '0.0000' is closest to 0.

So, I thought that maybe it was because I exported the data  from external software and that 0.0000 wasn't really 0.  But,

```
TIME[1]==0  #TRUE
```

Then I got further confused.  Why do these give the answer of index 1, when really they should be an ERROR?

```
which.min(0 > 0 ) #1
which.min(-1 > 0 ) #1
```

I'll be glad to be put right.

EDIT:

I guess in a nutshell, what is the better way to get this result:

```
#[1] 2  2  2  2  3  3  5  5  7  7  8  9  9  9 10 11 12  12  12
```

which shows the index of TIME that gives the smallest possible positive value, when subtracting each element of TIME from the values of 1 to 19.

Comment: `which.min(0 > 0)` shouldn't give an error. The argument returns `FALSE` and `which.min()` works fine on logical vectors; it returns the location of the first occurrence of `FALSE`, or `TRUE` if there are no false elements. Hence `which.min(0 > 0)` is 1 because its input has one element.

Comment: it's really hard to track down what exactly your question is

Comment: `which.min` is not very natural for logical vectors.

Comment: @Frank: True, but its behavior for logical vectors is documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural function to use here (both to limit typing and for efficiency) is actually not `which.min` + `sapply` but the `cut` function, which will determine which range of times each of the values 1:19 falls into:

```
cut(1:19, breaks=TIME, right=FALSE)
# [1] [0,4.47)    [0,4.47)    [0,4.47)    [0,4.47)    [4.47,6.11) [4.47,6.11) [6.74,8.17)
# [8] [6.74,8.17) [8.81,10)   [8.81,10)   [10,11)     [11,14.8)   [11,14.8)   [11,14.8)  
# [15] [14.8,15.5) [15.5,16.5) [16.5,17.1) <NA>        <NA>       
# 11 Levels: [0,4.47) [4.47,6.11) [6.11,6.74) [6.74,8.17) [8.17,8.81) ... [16.5,17.1)
```

From this, you can easily determine what you're looking for, which is the index of the smallest element in `TIME` greater than the cutoff:

```
(x <- as.numeric(cut(1:19, breaks=TIME, right=FALSE))+1)
# [1]  2  2  2  2  3  3  5  5  7  7  8  9  9  9 10 11 12 NA NA
```

The last two entries appear as NA because there is no element in `TIME` that exceeds 18 or 19. If you wanted to replace these with the largest element in `TIME`, you could do so with `replace`:

```
replace(x, is.na(x), length(TIME))
# [1]  2  2  2  2  3  3  5  5  7  7  8  9  9  9 10 11 12 12 12
```

Comment: Similarly, `findInterval(1:19,TIME,all.inside=TRUE)+1L`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
x <- t(outer(TIME,1:19,`-`))            
max.col(ifelse(x<0,x,Inf),ties="first")
#  [1]  2  2  2  2  3  3  5  5  7  7  8  9  9  9 10 11 12 12 12
```

It's computationally wasteful to take all the differences in this way, since both vectors are ordered.